# Usar o java para achar uma imagem na tela

Tags: java, imagem

Como posso fazer para o java ler uma image na tela, a intenção é fazer um bot, assim que ver a img clica nela, a img não está em um navegador,site,ou algo da web, e sim em um programa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade há uma **solução** bem viável para isso. Você pode implementar as bibliotecas **Sikuli** para dentro do seu aplicativo `Java`para detetar elementos de imagem no ecrã e interagir com eles.

Esta **biblioteca** foi concebida para automatizar testes de interface por parte do usuário, mas pode acomodar as suas necessidades com bastante facilidade!

Segue um exemplo de um pequeno código que faz exatamente isso que você pretende:

[Source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sikuli-api/)

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.sikuli.api.*;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.Mouse;
import org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopMouse;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.Canvas;
import org.sikuli.api.visual.DesktopCanvas;

import static org.sikuli.api.API.*;

public class HelloWorldExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

       // Open the main page of Google Code in the default web browser
       browse(new URL("http://code.google.com"));

       // Create a screen region object that corresponds to the default monitor in full screen 
       ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();

       // Specify an image as the target to find on the screen
       URL imageURL = new URL("http://code.google.com/images/code_logo.gif");                
       Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(imageURL);

       // Wait for the target to become visible on the screen for at most 5 seconds
       // Once the target is visible, it returns a screen region object corresponding
       // to the region occupied by this target
       ScreenRegion r = s.wait(imageTarget,5000);

       // Display "Hello World" next to the found target for 3 seconds
       Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
       canvas.addLabel(r, "Hello World").display(3);

       // Click the center of the found target
       Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
       mouse.click(r.getCenter());
 }
}
```

Pode também **consultar**:

[Como usar Sikuli nos seus projetos em Java](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html)